# HTML5 email field giving "blank" warning message in latest FF 35

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, firefox

I have an email input on a form. It has a default value. When you `focus` on it, it blanks out the field if the value is equal to the default. When you `blur` the element, it sets the default if the field is blank.

The issue is that if you click the submit button when the email is blank (or the default) it makes FF respond with an empty warning message instead of "Please enter an email address." This only happens in the latest FF 35

[image]

The problem doesn't happen if I remove either the `focus` or `blur` event. I can't use `place holders` or the `required` attribute or anything else like that because this needs to be IE8 compatible.

**How can I fix this?** I do not want to use any external plugin or library. The change should be as minimal as possible. I can't change the behavior - the form still has to function as it currently functions.

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
<input data-default='Email*' value="Email*" id=email type="email" />
    <input type=submit />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#email').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val()=="Email*") {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});

$('#email').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val()=="") {
        $(this).val($(this).data('default'));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkbgg8dr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do not empty the content of the email input box on focus as the browser validates the email and displays the appropriate message.

For cross browser validation implementation,

please take a look at

[jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)